# UdpClient Receive not receiving datagram

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, udp

I trying to write a TFTP client for a class project. 
Using the UdpClient class I can successfully request data from the server but the returned packet never reaches my code.

My firewall is turned off. 
I can observe the returned packet in wireshark but UdpClient.Receive blocks indefinitely.

mUdpClient is initialized like this in the constructor: `mUdpClient = new UdpClient();`

mUdpClient is connected like this

```
public void connect(String host, int port) {
    mServerAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];
    var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(mServerAddress, port);
    mUdpClient.Connect(endPoint);
}
```

After the connect I send my request which is successful (as observed in wireshark)

This is what my receive code looks like

```
private void receiveResponse() {
    var newEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    byte[] response = mUdpClient.Receive(ref newEndpoint);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(response);
}
```

This has been tested on my Surface Pro and a Windows 8.1 VirtualBox VM running under Debian.

Comment: Hard to say without more code and a reliable repro case. That said: how long do you wait before calling Receive() after you have already sent your first datagram? Is it possible that the OS has discarded the inbound datagram by that time?

Comment: Also, note that since you are using the Connect() method on your UDP socket, you will only see datagrams actually sent from that IP address. If your remote host for some reason uses a different IP address to send data back to you, you won't see it. So maybe try not using the default host feature (i.e. don't call Connect...just provide the remote IP address on each Send() call). Note also that some firewalls and NAT routers will only tunnel inbound datagrams back to the sender if they come from the original address to which a datagram was sent. What does wireshark say about inbound UDP traffic?

Comment: I am calling receive immediately after connect. I will sending without calling connect, but the data will always come from the same IP in this case so I am not sure if it will make a difference. Wireshark is showing me that the return data is reaching me, is there any other specific information you would like me to dig up? I am somewhat new to wireshark.

Comment: Turns out Connect was the issue. very strange. it appears to be working now. If you make that an answer to this question I will mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since you are using the Connect() method on your UDP socket, you will only see datagrams actually sent from that IPEndPoint. If your remote host for some reason uses a different IPEndPoint to send data back to you, you won't see it. So maybe try not using the default host feature (i.e. don't call Connect...just provide the remote IPEndPoint on each Send() call).

Comment: ... from that IP address, **and UDP port**.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have written "IPEndPoint", which is of course an address and a port. Mea culpa for being sloppy. I'll fix the answer.